How to automatically display ts type definitions in storybook

const mate = {
  title: 'MemoOrMessage',
  component: MemoOrMessage,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
} satisfies Meta<typeof MemoOrMessage>;

I'm currently using autodocs to generate documentation, which is great, but I want to display the specific definition of OrderDetail in description. How can I do it?
